# Windows Form Application update query not save data

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I try to use an update query in my C# windows form application. I do not get any errors, it just seems not to save the data I try to update. Take a look at the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string myConnection = connection;

        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        myConn.Open();

        MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = new MySqlCommand(" update users set username=" + textBox1.Text + " where username=" + username + " ", myConn);

        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        myConn.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Changes has been saved.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
    }
```

The username is an string passed from another form (gridview) ..

Comment: On where you execute your query exactly? Feels like you don't need `MySqlDataAdapter` and `ds` here. Have you tried your command on your database manager? Is it works there? And please use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also use _using statement_ to dispose your database connections.

Comment: Tried in my phpmyadmin and the query do NOT works! Thanks for tip me about try it there. Will resolve the query problem and try again

Comment: Tried with an working query, still not seems to save it. marc_s, the connection string is: `datasource=localhost;database=TESTDB;port=3306;username=root;password=root`

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution for this on the internet. What I cam up with is:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string myConnection = connection;
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE `users` SET username='Test' WHERE username='CurrentName' ", myConn);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {

            myConn.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            myConn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Changes has been saved!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```